# Concatenate cells between dynamic start and end row

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to concatenate a number of cells into one if they are between two cells with a certain string.

For example: In the Element column there are modalOpen and modalClose and in between those are modalFields. Between modalOpen and modalClose I need to add the Name of each row with Element modalField into the Output column for the modalOpen row.

The number of modalFields can vary from 2 - 20.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in **C** column and paste this in **C2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 
 SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(IF(B2:B<>"", 
 IF(A2:A="modalOpen", "♥"&B2:B&"♦"&B2:B&" with", 
 IF(A3:A="modalClose", "& <"&B2:B&">", "<"&B2:B&">,")), )
 ,,999^99), "♥")), "♦"), 2, 0)), ">, & ", "> & ")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Brilliant answer, please can you look at the extension of this question if you get a chance. Thank you. 

"Concatenate cells between dynamic start and end row with custom formulas"

Answer (score 0):

`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(IF(A2:A="modalClose","",IF(A2:A="modalOpen","♠"&B2:B&" with ","<"&B2:B&">,")),A2:A<>""),,2^99),"♠"))),"(, )(\<[^<>]\>),$"," and $2"))`

The result:

```
Test1 with <1>, <2> and  <3>
Test2 with <1>, <2>, <3> and  <4>
```